# Is there a way to wait for "az webapp restart" to be completed?

Tags: azure, docker

How do I know when my docker application in Azure has been restarted after running `az webapp restart`?

I would like to wait at the end of the upload script until the system is ready.

Comment: Are you using WebApp Linux, Windows or LinuxDocker?

Comment: WSL2 with Ubuntu

Comment: I mean hosting method WebApp - Windows | Linux?
Publishing method Code | Docker?

Comment: It is a Linux Docker container.

Answer (score 2):

When you run command `az webapp restart` this is just an API call to Azure, then Azure will restart your Docker container and send you 200 OK response.

`az webapp restart` will not wait when your Docker container is ready to serve requests.
To consider a container to be successfully started, the container must start and it must respond to an HTTP ping.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/ba-p/392472

I would recommend you to make a constant HTTP request(maybe in cycle every 1 second) to your application and if you receive 200 OK response, you can run upload script.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look at the logs using Azure CLI tool.

On your terminal run:

```
az webapp log tail --name <web_app_name> --resource-group <resource_group>
```

You can pipe this command into `grep` to search for a line indicating startup. After that message is retrieved you can act on it as you see fit.

My app is written in Golang, hence, after a restart I see the following output,

```
2024-01-12T21:30:00.377574751Z cp: target '/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors' is not a directory
2024-01-12T21:30:05.511290324Z Updated CA certificates
2024-01-12T21:30:10.527121828Z {"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Program","Message":"Entering app startup."}
2024-01-12T21:30:13.798483916Z Hosting environment: Production
2024-01-12T21:30:13.800208337Z Content root path: /app
2024-01-12T21:30:13.807109722Z Now listening on: http://[::]:8081
```

The key message is `Entering app startup.` and `listening on: http://[::]:8081`.